# Error 406 in request with content Type multipart/form

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I has a error in request with axios in express

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", fs.createReadStream(file.path));
formData.append("requestid", '123456');

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/api/v1/nfe',
  headers: {
    "Accept": "multipart/form-data",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    'Authorization':
      `Bearer ${getToken}`,
    ...formData.getHeaders()
  },
  data: formData
}

const results = await axios(options).then((response) => {
  return { statusCode: 200, body: { response, msg: 'success' } }
}).catch((error) => {
  return { statusCode: 400, body: { error, msg: 'failed' } }
})
```

I think it's something related to the application's content-type, but I can't solve it in any way and I've been stuck in this problem for a few days

But I received at error

```
"error": {
        "message": "Request failed with status code 406",
        "name": "Error",
        "stack": "Error: Request failed with status code 406\n    at createError (/process/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n    at settle (/process/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/process/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:269:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)\n    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:499:23)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1183:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)",
```

I need to help, please

Comment: `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",` is not the cause of your problem but *is* nonsense since (a) it is missing the *mandatory* `boundary` parameter  and (b) it will be overridden by `...formData.getHeaders()`

Answer (score 0):

A [406 response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406) means:

> the server cannot produce a response matching the list of acceptable values defined in the request's proactive content negotiation headers

You said:

> "Accept": "multipart/form-data",

This is not a data format normally used for responses (I've **never** encountered it in that context).

Why do you say you only accept that type of response? It's probably a mistake.

Axios is focused on dealing with `application/json` responses (although it can handle most things to some extent).

---

Either:

- Change your accept header to a content-type the server can produce
- Remove your accept header and accept the default data format the server returns
- Change the server so it can respond with multipart/form-data